# implementing GDT in C

Tags: c, gdt

I am learning to write an OS, and was trying to update GDT in kernel code, therefore i defined some structs in C

```
typedef unsigned int   u32;
typedef          int   s32;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef          short s16;
typedef unsigned char  u8;
typedef          char  s8;

typedef struct{
    u16 low_limit;
    u16 low_base;
    u8 mid_base;
    u8 type; // access type
    u8 flags; // high 4 bits(flags) low 4 bits (limit 4 last bits)
    u8 high_base;
} __attribute__((packed)) gdt_gate_t;

typedef struct{
    u16 limit;
    u32 base;
}__attribute__((packed)) gdt_register_t;

typedef struct{
    u8 RPL : 2; // Request Privilege Level
    u8 TI : 1; // Table Indicator (GDT or LDT)
    u16 index : 13;
}__attribute__((packed)) gdt_selector_t;

gdt_gate_t gdt[128];
gdt_register_t gdt_reg;
```

As you can see, i am aming to create GDT with 128 entries.

After i initialized GDT entries, i told `gdt_reg` where is the base of the new GDT and it's limit using

```
gdt_reg.base = (u32)&gdt;
gdt_reg.limit = sizeof(gdt) - 1;
__asm__ __volatile__("lgdt (%0)" : : "r"(&gdt_reg));
```

In my environment, memory address of variable `gdt` beginns at `0x00004820`, so the value stored in `gdt_reg.base` should be as expected `0x00004820`. But actually in the memory, the value is `00 00 20 48`(little endian), then the regester `gdtr` has value `48200000(3ff)`, which means the `gdtr` points to an illegal address.

So the question is, why the value of `gdt_reg.base` was reversed.
Many thanks for any help

Comment: instead of weird `u32` typedef-ed non portable way, I would use the standard `uint32_t`

Comment: `typedef          char  s8;`  This bug is exactly why we don't make our own rotten non-standard types. Use `stdint.h`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. But that is not the reason. The reason is that the compiler didn't recognized `__attribute__((packed))`, so the memory for struct `gdt_register_t` is aligned, which turns out `u16 limit` occupys 4 bytes in the memory.